# Where are the eclipse product build scripts stored?

Tags: eclipse, build, rcp

i'm exporting an eclipse product with the eclipse Product export wizard. when i run this wizard a lot of build scripts are generated and executed - i want to re-use these build scripts for my p2e-build. where does eclipse store these build scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files for the build are created in the root folder of the project containing the xxx.product file you are using. They only exist while the build is running. The main file is a `build.xml` Ant script.

Comment: after the build proces... will eclipse delete these files?

Comment: I don't know. There are more official ways of doing builds such as using Maven + Tycho.

Comment: ok, still fighting with tycho/maven - thanks anyway... (they ARE deleted after export)....